# How to redirect a URL that has %something% in it

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have a URL that is being incorrectly indexed by Google. It looks like this:

`www.domain.co.uk/category/%something%`

The percentage signs seem to be causing a server issue so I just want to redirect the URL to a different page. However, I'm not sure how to do this when a URL contains percentage signs.

It's an nginx server and a WordPress website so I have tried the Redirection plugin but can't seem to get it working.

Can anybody shine some light?

Comment: The question is what percentage signs are doing in your URLs. That character has a special meaning in URLs. You should read a bit about that. So either that character is used to encode non printable characters in your URLs (which definitely should _not_ cause any issues in whatever server you are talking about) or those URLs are invalid.

Comment: You state that it's an Nginx server, yet you've tagged it `.htaccess`? An unencoded `%` in the URL-path is strictly invalid. Apache will trigger a 400 Bad Request _before_ `.htaccess` is able to process the URL. Not sure about Nginx.

Comment: Downvote for not fully understanding the very thing I'm posting to get help with? Bit mystifying.

Loading the URL returns a 400 bad request error. I guess that means I can't use htaccess to do anything here? Again, not trying to mislead anyone. Simply looking for advice on how to get around this. The URL has been indexed somehow from custom code to create a custom post type, custom taxonomy and chain them together in the permalink rather than use WordPress' default settings. I just want to remove this specific link/unindex it/redirect it

Comment: The only way to resolve this on Apache would be to define a custom error document in the server config (or virtualhost) - `.htaccess` is _too late_. Your error document itself can then examine the request and override the response, redirecting as required. (`.htaccess` is not part of Nginx - which is a little confusing in your question.)

Comment: @MrWhite, ah, that's what I wasn't understanding. Redirection won't work, htaccess won't work, needs action earlier on. Thank you for clarifying.